# How to configure FastCGI on IIS 6 to load Perl modules correctly

Tags: perl, iis-6, fastcgi

I've achieved several partial successes, but can't cross the last hurdle.

Symptom: When in test mode FastCGI performs perfectly. When running plain perl scripts in eval or do mode it performs perfectly. As soon as I attempt to access the FCGI::Request() object or the CGI::Fast->new object, it hangs indefinitely. Here's my config:

```
[Types]
fcgi=FCGI
cgi=FCGI
pl=FCGI
pm=FCGI

[FCGI]
ExePath=C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
;ExePath=C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
Arguments="-MFCGI::IIS=eval"
;Arguments=d:\inetpub\cgi-bin\hello.fcgi
;Arguments=d:\inetpub\cgi-bin\h2.fcgi
ActivityTimeout=5
QueueLength=999
MaxInstances=20
InstanceMaxRequests=500
```

You can see the things I've tried referenced above with ;'s. Using ActiveState or Strawberry results in the same behavior. If I set the -MFCGI::IIS argument equal to "test", it runs the tests perfectly. Eval, do, and no setting all hang indefinitely.

Most tellingly, if I set the Arguments = to a valid FCGI file (or .pl/.cgi/.pm) then that single script will run perfectly. The perl instance persists across calls precisely as it should, and it runs with advertised speed. The calls to the FCGI::Request() or CGI::Fast->new methods all return the objects they should. Everything is positively hunky dory, but that's not the correct config. I have a raft of cgi files, and I'd have to create a separate mapping entry for each cgi file to make that ugly kludge work.

I suspect I'm missing a setting that causes the name of the script to be sent as an argument to perl, but I can't see the param. Thanks for any help.

Edit: My suspicion is incorrect. FCGI is definitely calling the correct scripts, but it's calling them with the wrong environment somehow. If I use the -MFCGI::IIS argument, I call exactly the same script as if I use the explicit path argument, but when I use the explicit path argument the scripts can find their libraries. My challenge is to get the scripts to identify their libraries correctly.

When using -MFCGI::IIS this script fails:

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl
use CGI::Fast;
```

The error is:

```
Error! 
Can't locate object method "FILENO" via package "FCGI::Stream" at 
C:/Perl/lib/CGI.pm line 822. 
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/lib/CGI/Fast.pm line 20. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/lib/CGI/Fast.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 4. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 4.
```

When using an explicit script reference, this script succeeds completely. It maintains the same perl PID, maintains its count, and returns accurate values. Mostly, though, it can import its modules.

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

use CGI::Fast; 
my $count = 1; 
while (my $q = CGI::Fast->new) 
{ 
        print("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"); 
        print("Process ID: $$; Count is: " . ++$count); 
}
```

There has just got to be some ENV var I can set to make perl able to find its modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft reports their FastCGI tool is not tested with Perl. You can't get there from here. On the other hand, you can make progress using IIS 7 and PerlEx30.dll. I had some luck with that before being called to another project.